# How to get auto-incremented keys using JDBC and Microsoft Access?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, primary-key

I'm writing a computer program using Java (JDBC) and I'm having trouble getting auto-incremented keys from my Microsoft Access database. Currently I have three instances of Connection, Statement and ResultSet from the java.sql.* package.

What do I do to get a generated key from my database for a row, and then set that value to a String so I can display it in a text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

Disclaimer: May not be supported by your driver.

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoGetGeneratedKeysMySQL.htm)